# Subsetting Longitudinal Dataframe by Randomly Selected Participant ID

Tags: r, subset, random

I'd like to subset a longitudinal dataset by a randomly sampled number of participants. In this example there are three entries per participant and I want to sample 4 participants.

```
id <- rep(c(1:6), each = 3)
score <- rnorm(18, 10, 3)
group <- rep(c("a", "b"), each = 3, times = 3)

df <- data.frame(id, group, score)
```

I tried with this command...

```
dfSub <- df[df$id %in% sample(df$id, 4, replace = FALSE),]
```

But it only returns the entries for three participants, not the four I stipulated. Can anyone tell me why this didn't work and how to do it better?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `unique`

```
df[df$id %in%sample(unique(df$id), 4, replace = FALSE),]
#   id group     score
#7   3     a  8.123872
#8   3     a 12.685344
#9   3     a 12.824781
#10  4     b 11.868296
#11  4     b 13.000660
#12  4     b  9.541258
#13  5     a  9.722255
#14  5     a  3.889751
#15  5     a 10.851232
#16  6     b 10.945997
#17  6     b 11.632380
#18  6     b  3.289507
```

The OP's command didn't work out because of the following

```
 sample(c(1, 1, 4,3), 3, replace=FALSE)
 #[1] 3 4 1
 sample(c(1, 1, 4,3), 3, replace=FALSE)
 #[1] 1 3 1
```

If there are duplicate values, `sample` can still return duplicates instead of `unique` values for the `size` specified.  The `replace` only does whether sampling  should be done with replacement or not.  In the dummy example, we have 2 `1s`.  So, even with `replace=FALSE`, the number of 1s that can be possible in the `sample` is 2.

Comment: Thank you @akrun, but I'm not sure i really understand. I have tried my old command a few times and sometimes it returns 4 x 3 entries and sometimes it returns three. Are you saying the minimum that could be returned with my command is 2 x 3, because without the 'unique' stipulation it could randomly select 1,1,1,3 or 2,2,2,6 or 5,2,5,5 etc? If so then that makes sense.

Comment: @llewmils As I mentioned, the `replacement=FALSE` will make sure that you will not have 4 1s if the initial number of duplicates are only 3 and the `size` selected is 4.